# How to validate a valid integer and floating number in VC++ CString

Tags: c++, mfc

Can some one tell me a valid way to validate a number present in CString object as either a valid integer or floating number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [_tcstol()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4z2wdyc.aspx) and [_tcstod()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxsfc1ab.aspx):

```
bool IsValidInt(const CString& text, long& value)
{
    LPCTSTR ptr = (LPCTSTR) text;
    LPTSTR endptr;
    value = _tcstol(ptr, &endptr, 10);
    return (*ptr && endptr - ptr == text.GetLength());
}

bool IsValidFloat(const CString& text, double& value)
{
    LPCTSTR ptr = (LPCTSTR) text;
    LPTSTR endptr;
    value = _tcstod(ptr, &endptr);
    return (*ptr && endptr - ptr == text.GetLength());
}
```

**EDIT:** Modified the code to follow the excellent suggestions provided in the comments.

Comment: It's often useful to capture the result as well. Most of the times you intend to use the numerical value if it validated.

Comment: Just noticed that an empty string in text also returns true. An additional check to catch any empty string at the beginning might be useful.

Comment: @xml-tools.com, very true, I added a `NUL` character check to achieve this. Thanks :)

Comment: An other minor note, use static_cast<LPCTSTR>(Text) instead of the c-style casting used now.