# Using _tcstod correctly and setting lpszEndChar to NULL or not

Tags: c++, mfc

I saw the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030337/how-to-validate-a-valid-integer-and-floating-number-in-vc-cstring) and have read the original documentation.

So their code:

```
bool IsValidFloat(const CString& text, double& value)
{
    LPCTSTR ptr = (LPCTSTR) text;
    LPTSTR endptr;
    value = _tcstod(ptr, &endptr);
    return (*ptr && endptr - ptr == text.GetLength());
}
```

Some of my users have been encountering a issue and I think I have narrowed it down to:

```
LPCTSTR lpszValue = (LPCTSTR)strWord ; 
LPTSTR lpszEndChar = NULL ; 
double dLineSpace = _tcstod(lpszValue, &lpszEndChar);
```

I noticed that in the sample above `endptr` is not defaulted to `NULL`. Nor the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtod-strtod-l-wcstod-wcstod-l?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019) (where they simply use `char *string, *stopstring;`).

Is this the reason my code is failing? Is there a specific reason why we can't default `lpszEndChar` to `NULL`?

Comment: The actual value (address) in `endptr` is not used as an *input* value, so you shouldn't need to initialize it (but I can't see any harm in doing so). If you pass a null address of that optional pointer, then the `strtod` family of functions won't give you a next-after-number pointer, that's all.

Comment: Could your users' problem come from locale-related issues (dots vs commas for decimal, or some such)?

Comment: @AdrianMole the problem was the fact that my code intended on using the next-after-number pointer for working out the lengths. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: @AdrianMole It could possibly be a locale issue. Since one of the users in Danish and the log info he has provided me uses commas. I will have to wait and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give one of the [`strtod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/) family of functions (which includes `_tcstod` on Windows/MSVC builds) a *non-NULL* argument as the second, `endptr` argument (that is, the address of a valid *pointer* variable), then it doesn't (or *shouldn't*) matter what address *value* that pointer has (even if it is `NULL`) when you call the function: it is an 'output-only' argument. If you pass an *actual* `NULL` as the second argument, then the functions won't (can't) modify what is (not) pointed-to.

In your case, you are comparing `*endptr - str` (note the dereference on the first) with the length of the entire string, to check for a valid read. This makes the assumption that there are no 'extra' characters after the number (even whitespace).

A more likely cause of this test failing is that floating-point numbers are being given in the wrong locale; so, if your locale is set the the default "C" (expecting a dot decimal point), and a number is given as "12,34" (in European format), then `12` will be successfully read from the string, but `*endptr` will point at the `3`.

To address the locale issue, there are a couple of options. First (if you know the 'origin' locale), you can use the [`setlocale`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/setlocale/) function before calling `_tcstod` to set the appropriate decimal character:

```cpp
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, FRENCH_LOCALE);
double dLineSpace = _tcstod(lpszValue, &lpszEndChar); 
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C"); // Revert to default, 'C' locale
```

Or, if you're not sure whether the decimals will be dots or commas, you should first replace any commas with dots. If your data are (initially) in a `CString` variable, and you *only* have a number in it, then you can use the [`CString::Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=vs-2019#replace) function:

```cpp
myString.Replace(_T(','), _T('.'));
//...
```

However, if your `CString` is more complex than just a single number (or isn't a `CString`), you will have to write a small function to do the replacement(s) for you. (I can maybe offer a hint, if that's what you need!)

Comment: Yes, it was the locale issue.